# Git diff randomly missing added lines

Tags: git, version-control, git-diff

I've noticed a strange phenomenon on one of my projects that is under git version control. When a line has been changed, 'git diff' will show the old line as deleted but will not show the "new" line as added. This happens randomly and other changed lines (even within the same file) still show correctly. Here is the example I'm looking at right now:

```
-    this.vehicleUseId = data.Get<short?>("vehicleUseId");
-    this.radiusId = data.Get<short?>("radiusId");
-    this.vehicleSubClassId = data.Get<short?>("vehicleSubClassId");
+    this.vehicleUseId = data.GetNullable<short>("vehicleUseId");
+    this.radiusId = data.GetNullable<short>("radiusId");
+    this.vehicleSubClassId = data.GetNullable<short>("vehicleSubClassId");
     this.vehicleClassId = ...
-    this.garageZoneNum = data.Get<short?>("garageZoneNum");
-    this.destZoneNum = data.Get<short?>("destZoneNum");
+    this.destZoneNum = data.GetNullable<short>("destZoneNum");
```

So five lines were changed in the exact same way and only one of them is missing. I have double checked and the corrected line for 'garageZoneNum' is indeed still in the source file.

This has happened under similar circumstances about five times, too many for me to continue to ignore. Is 'git diff' supposed to be 100% reliable or is there an expectation that anomalies will occur from time to time?

Comment: It is 100% reliable. Do you have weird line endings or something like that causing your terminal program to overwrite things?

Comment: I don't think so - this is a project that has been created and edited entirely using Visual Studio. Although I do run git independently from VS using the regular DOS prompt.

Comment: Ah, there is something weird with the terminal - if I scroll past the questionable spot and then go back up to it, everything is shown correctly. But then if I scroll back past it in the other direction and come back down to it, back to showing incorrectly. Any idea of how I can remedy this?

Comment: Use a different terminal? Log the diff to a file? Dunno. I'm no windows expert, I'm afraid.